# 98 grand prix RPM dropping to 0

Tags: engine, transmission, grand-prix

My 98 grand prix has 236,000mi on it and recently my rpms will drop to 0 and its a 50/50 on whether or not it kills the engine. Shutting it off and on again resets it and when it dosnt kill the engine it seems to run normal.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you measure/monitor fuel pressure? Fuel filter ever replaced? No one can state when a fuel pump wears out or fails long after new car warranty and a fuel pressure gauge may help.